# error while trying to send an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuelidate

I have to fix a bug that some data is missing when sending the form. I have this typescript interface

```
  _id: string
  name: string
  coords?: number[] 
  createdAt?: Date
  updatedAt?: Date
  deletedAt?: Date
}
```

these are my props:

```
props: {
    data: {
      type: Object as PropType<Location>,
      default: () => ({
        _id: null,
        name: '',
        createdAt: '',
        updatedAt: ''
      })
    }
  },
```

and this is how I´m creating the v-model:

```
const location = reactive({ ...props.data } as Location)

    const rules = {
      name: { required },
      coords: { required }
    }
    const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, location)
```

And I´m having an error like this

```
 Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<any>'.
    76 |       coords: { required }
    77 |     }
  > 78 |     const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, location)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cords are required on rules, either set a default value for it or remove optional properties in the Location interface